# In rust how can i do this type conversion in one line

Tags: rust

I am trying to use a bit shift but I need the result as an f64. I can't seem to figure how how to shift and let the result as an f64 without making an ugly tmp varible.

```
let num_bits: uint = 32; // just for reference

// how can these two lines be 1 line
let muli: int = 1<<(num_bits-2);
let mul: f64 = muli as f64;
```

How can I write the last two line as one line so I don't need `muli`?

I have tried made various attempts in the theme of:

```
 let m: f64 = 1<<(num_bits-2) as f64;
```

which gives [playpen](http://is.gd/4yhKLi)

```
  <anon>:8:21: 8:40 error: mismatched types: expected `uint`, found `f64` (expected uint, found f64)
  <anon>:8     let m: f64 = 1<<(num_bits-2) as f64;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by annotating the type of the `1` literal. I'm assuming you want it the shift result to be an `int` (before converting to `f64`) since you said `multi: int`. Otherwise, you want `1u`.

```
let m: f64 = (1i << (num_bits - 2)) as f64;
```

Check the [playpen](http://is.gd/O4kADB).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there an a value for `num_bits` where `1u` and `1i` would give different results for `m`?

Comment: If it's just a `1` that's being shifted, nope. I was explicit anyways in case this question was a generalized form of your actual code, which may not be shifting a `1`.

Comment: @Victory: beware that in Rust, `int` and `uint` number of bits vary from platform to platform. If you want specifically a 64-bits integer, then you should use `i64` or `u64`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at rust reference you can see that `as` operator has higher precedence than `<<` so you have to do:

```
fn main () {
    let num_bits: uint = 32; // just for reference
    let m: f64 = (1u << num_bits - 2) as f64;
    println!("mul {}", mul);
}
```

You also must specify the bype of `1` as `uint` (`1u`) because the compiler cannot deretmine the type for it from the context when written that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It was equally good to the other but, Jorge's was earlier so i have to accept his. I still +1 yours. I also asked a question in the other answer if you are interested in looking.